# Facebook JS SDK into asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, cache-control, facebook-sdk-3.0

Facebook SDK is the most heavy file of all my website. It require about 5sec to load.

[image]

This is because **Cache-control** is set to **389sec**. Do know a way to extend it to at least a week?
Could be a good practice to **insert all.js into my "asset pipeline"** and set cache expire by fingerprint?

[image]

**FacebookSDK.js.coffee**

```
initializeFacebookSDK = ->
  FB.init
    channelUrl   : '//website.herokuapp.com/page/fbchannel'
    cookie       : true
    xfbml        : true
    status       : false
    oauth        : false
```

**PageController**

```
class PageController < ApplicationController

def fbchannel
    cache_expire = 1.year
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "public"
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=#{cache_expire.to_i}"
    response.headers["Expires"] = (Time.now + cache_expire).strftime("%d %m %Y %H:%I:%S %Z")
    render :layout => false, :inline => "<script src='//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js'></script>"
  end
end
```

Comment: all.js supports ETags, so even if the resource expires locally, the ETag should keep it from having to be loaded again.
That said, the expiration should not be as short as 6 minutes. Are you sure you have no proxies that are changing the headers?

Comment: I'm using Mobile Tethering wifi. This could be the reason?